# Login Failure when Testing with Capybara, Rspec and Selenium in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I added some confirmation dialog boxes for my Rails 3.1 application and, prior to that, their corresponding tests. Following the model of [Railscast #257](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara), I added ':js => true' to the test, added database_cleaner and modified the spec_helper.rb file accordingly.

When I run the test, Firefox launches, Capybara-Selenium fills in the fields the the appropriate username and a password, but log-in fails (i.e., "invalid username/password".) Other tests that do not have ':js => true' and also login, do still pass.

I would like to add more javascript to my application in the future and I am avoiding solutions that would hack Capybara to get this to work (e.g., click 'OK' on all dialogs.)

Any ideas what I might be missing? Fail that, any suggestions on how to debug this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should set use_transactional_fixtures = false for your seleniumtests.
This can be done in the spec_helper.rb with

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

for all your tests.

Or do this for a single testcase:

```
describe 'testcase' , :type => :request do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  it 'your test', :js => :true do
    testing...
  end
end
```

This happens because selenium-tests access the database in a different way. With transactional fixtures enabled, selenium will work on an empty database -> your user does not exist and you cannot login.

For normal tests you should use transactional fixtures because your tests run much faster.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I had transactional fixtures disabled in my spec_helper.rb and it did not work. But doing it with in the specific test did work! It logged me in and failed the test when it clicked the button. But the confirm dialog appeared, now I just need to figure out how to click it through the integration test. Thanks again!

Comment: if it is a common rails dialog you can try: page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept

Comment: What if i am using mongoid? i cant set use_transactional_fixtures = false

Comment: The way you describe solution for a single test case is wrong. The value of `use_transactional_fixtures` property will be saved for all following examples. Therefore the solution by @onemanarmy below is right for this case.

Answer (score 9):

As per [Avdi Grimm's post](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/) (features a detailed explanation):

**Gemfile:**

```
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

**spec_helper.rb:**

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

**spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

I had transactional fixtures disabled but adding the `:js => true` block to `database_cleaner.rb` did it for me.